# Sliding Menu on every view controller in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

When I open Detail screen by clicking on any tableview row of Menu-1 Screen, I want the Second screen to also have that same menu which is there in Menu-1 Screen and a back button for navigating to Menu-1 screen. i.e. **I want the Sliding menu in every view controller that I navigate.**

Here is my [SlideMenuProject.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzolC8EgXkB1eVh1SFRzTTdUQUU/view?usp=sharing).

My Project Screens:

[image: My Project Screens]

Comment: you should upload your project to github

Comment: btw: the library is very old - you should use a newer slide menu with swift 3 (since 09/2016)

Comment: I'm already in the middle of my project completion. I cannot waste time for using another library. I have to find a way out of this situation.

Comment: @muescha Why uploading to GitHub? The code that OP wants to fix should be posted on Stack Overflow, in the question, in an [MCVE]. Please don't tell people to put their code on GitHub, it should go in the question.

Comment: But OP should first be posting in the GitHub project for assistance, as the advice will be very specific to this old version of the framework. OP you are much more likely to get quick help from asking in GitHub. At the very least include a link in your question to the GitHub project.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller They should first ask on GitHub, sure, to the "PhilippeBoisney/Swift-Slide-Menu" author, but now they're posting on Stack Overflow, and when doing so, it is mandatory to use an [mcve] and to not have the relevant code hosted on a third-party site but in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by 2 ways.

step 1:

Create a `UIViewController` with sliding menu and subclass it to as many view controllers you need sliding menu.

step 2:

You can create an extension with the function to add slider menu. Then call the function in each view controller.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addMenuButton() {
        let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
    }
```

and call each ViewController the `addMenuButton()` function in `viewDidLoad()` of ViewControllers which requires sliding menu.

hope this helps.