# how to reuse the bar button for the slide menu on every controller view

Tags: ios, side-menu

I've built a slide menu that works fine. Each button leads to a new view controller. Rather than clicking on the back button of the subview view contoller to return to the main view controller to switch to the next function, I'd like from every view controller to have the same sliding menu.

I want in the image below to replace "< Test app" with my sliding menu icon pointing to the same menu as the main one.

[image]

I've read [Sliding Menu on every view controller in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922219/sliding-menu-on-every-view-controller-in-swift) but it's still unclear. I'm new to xcode/ios.

I can't find some good doc on how to do that. Where can I find doc, tuto for what I would like to do?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Create a class with name **"BaseMenuController"** inherit with subclass **UIViewController**.

**Step 2**

In BaseMenuController, paste following code.

```
import UIKit

class BaseMenuController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addMenuBarButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func addMenuBarButtonItem() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "side_menuImage")
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image,
                                       style: .plain,
                                       target: self,
                                       action: #selector(showSideMenu))

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem

    }

    @objc func showSideMenu(){
    if (UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight)       {
        self.sideMenuViewController.presentLeftMenuViewController()
    }else{
        self.sideMenuViewController.presentRightMenuViewController()
    }

   }
}
```

**Step 3**

Now your Controller Class is ready. you only need to inherit **BaseMenuController** When you create a new Controller Class. Give **BaseMenuController** class as a subclass.

```
import UIKit

class UIViewController:BaseMenuController  {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me for my stupid questions! Now I have a button in my sliding menu that is connected to a view controller to "show" the view controller. Where goes this code? in the viewcontroller.swift of my base controller? When I click on the menu button what func is called? on top of the show mechanism, I need to connect the button with an action function, I presume? what would you recommen in terms of doc I need to read first? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @narb you don't need any button or creating outlets. you just need to push the Viewcontroller. The SideMenu button is appear. You just to inherit class with BaseMenuController.

Comment: so when I click on the button (in the sliding menu), what method is called?

Comment: When you inherit your controller class with BaseMenuController. you already see that menu button is appear and when you click on side Menu button showSideMenu() is called.

Comment: Here is the usage of it.
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        let sideMenu = SideMenuViewController(nibName: "SideMenuViewController", bundle: nil)
        let homePage = HomePageViewControllerNew(nibName: "HomePageViewControllerNew", bundle: nil)
        if(openShelf){
            homePage.segementindex = 1
            homePage.isOpenMySHelf = true
        }
        navigationController.viewControllers = [homePage]

Comment: let sideMenuController = RESideMenu(contentViewController: navigationController, leftMenuViewController: sideMenu, rightMenuViewController: nil)
            sideMenuController?.scaleContentView = false
            sideMenuController?.scaleMenuView = false
            
 
                sideMenuController?.contentViewInPortraitOffsetCenterX = 100
        
            window?.rootViewController = sideMenuController

Answer (score 1):

You can add SideMenu Button your BaseViewController class.

```
func addMenuButtonToNavigationBar(){
    self.leftSearchBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "side_menu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(showSideMenu))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.leftSearchBarButtonItem;
}
@objc func showSideMenu(){
    if (UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight) {
        self.sideMenuViewController.presentLeftMenuViewController()
    }else{
        self.sideMenuViewController.presentRightMenuViewController()
    }
}
```

And in every view controller's viewwillappear() method call above method like this
    self.addMenuButtonToNavigationBar()

I am using pod for sidemen.
https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

Comment: Interesting but I'd prefer a swift approach and that's a lot of C code. Moreover I'd like to understand the mechanism rather than copying code.

Comment: ok let me try to understand you.
you have to create a baseViewController.
and add a method names addSideMenuButton to NavigationBar
After that Every view controller in your app should be inherited from BaseViewController.
then you would be able to access this method.

Comment: I think this is what I want to do. I'm porting an android app so I'm new to xcode. I have a navigation controller and a main viewcontroller in which I've defined the sliding menu. Each button of the sliding menu leads to a new controller view. when I am in a functio A and I want to go to function B, I need to click back and click a second time on function B. I would have liked to have a bar button on each view controller that points to the same sliding menu.

Comment: yes I've seen. quite nice. but it's in objc... I don't have pb with C but I'm a beginner with swift+xcode. convince me! :)

Comment: RESideMenuStoryboards and RESideMenuExample are 100% objC. I got it following your url!? Am I looking at a wrong url?

Comment: yes its in ObjC.
But you can use it in Swift code as well.
I am using it in swift code.